# my odbc connection is too slow using sql 2012 netbeans 7.3 windows 8

Tags: java, sql, windows-8, odbc

I have made  a form in netbeans 7.3 and connect with SQL 2012(ODBC) using windows 8
It connects but it takes time to give result

for example

```
try
{
   Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Restaurant");
   Statement st =  con.createStatement();
   ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select SUM (total) FROM ORDER_DETAIL WHERE ORDER_ID = "+jTextField8.getText());
   while (rs.next())
   {
      jLabel14.setText(rs.getString(1));
   }                                       
   con.close();           
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   System.out.println(e);
}
```

it is on focus lost event when it loses focus it takes 10-15 sec to show the result

Comment: You'll need to give us more detail than that - what query are you running? What's your table structure? Do you have any indexes? etc.

Comment: is it enough @GrandMasterFlush

Comment: Is ORDER_ID set as an index in the database?

Comment: Why do you use the JDBC/ODBC bridge? It's slow, buggy, deprecated and will be removed in Java8!. Use a native JDBC driver instead. Either jTDS or the Microsoft Driver.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can change the database, make ORDER_ID an index - doing this should speed up the query. I'm guessing that as the table is called Order_Detail that the Order_ID column is going to be used a lot when querying and this should help your query run faster.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx) page details how to add indexes to columns on MS SQL Server.